# Add C++ compiler to Eclipse C project

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

Hi I am currently developing a C application in eclipse and now I need to compile a library which uses C++. Is there a way to add .cpp handling (MinGW C++ Compiler) to and existing C Project in Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Can't you just change your project to a C++ project?

Comment: If it were so easy I would have done that.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this post on the Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/154099/), just add

```
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
```

to the the `<natures></natures>` tag of your `.project` file.

Comment: No it already has the C/C++ nature but doesn't have the code discovery for .cpp files...

Comment: You should have made it clear in your question that this was the problem. And what do you mean by code discovery? Autocomplete?

Comment: It was clear in the question I said that it is an existing *C Project*, anyhow what i meant was C/C++ Build->Discovery Options. In C++ Project there is a Tool for .cpp and .C files in my C project only for .c files so I have to add the .cpp Tool but I don't know how.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. The [Eclipse help](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_conv_proj.htm) suggests that there also is a "nicer" way to do this. Didn't test it, since I didn't want Eclipse to mess with other settings.